# Changing the value of crossDomainSessionSecurity in DWR to false in production

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, web.xml, dwr

I have a web application which uses DWR configuration in web.xml. I was given a task to migrate the application from WebSphere 6.0 to JBoss 6 AS. After the migration,  the application gives an alert with message: "Session Error" on two screens at the time of opening (However, the application works smoothly).

When the value of "crossDomainSessionSecurity" is changed to false in web.xml, the issue is resolved and the screen does not gives the alert.

What I want to ask is that:
-What is DWR (Sorry, I do not have any idea about DWR) ?

-Changing the value of "crossDomainSessionSecurity" to false will create any problem ?

-If there is no problem in changing the value to false, can I deploy the code in production ?

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: I had the same problem and changing `crossDomainSessionSecurity` to false solved it, but it was on an internal program, not sure if you should use it on a live application, they recommend "Do not set this to false without understanding the consequences." see more here

 http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/documentation/server/configuration/servlet/index.html

Comment: Thanks @Elye.

I saw that. But I'm not sure how to solve this issue without setting this configuration to false. I cannot send this code to production. Neither I'm able to solve the Session Error alert. 

Please help.

Comment: Please help. I'm not able to find any solution.